# How to fix the error 'Compiler crashed with code: 1' when using VB.net in MonoDevelop?

Tags: vb.net

I am a new programmer and a new Linux user. I was programming the other day on my laptop running Ubuntu 16.04, when i encountered the error in MonoDevelop:

```
/usr/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets: Error: Compiler crashed with code: 1. (NewProject)
```

The piece of code which had the problem was:

```
Public Class Application
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        System.Console.WriteLine("Hello world!")
    End Sub
End Class
```

I believe my question is different than others because I am experiencing this problem in VB.Net and not in any other programming language such as C# which also has this error in MonoDevelop. I noted that this error is only present when i build the solution using Release option and not Debug option. Can anybody please tell me how to fix the errors? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd be tempted to reinstall. To have the compiler crashing on something so simple suggests to me that something is corrupt.

Comment: Thank you @jmcilhinney, your advice worked for me.